# Are these two functions describing spring motion in the same way?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a differential equation in the form

$m\ddot{x} + kx = 0$

then the solution is in the form

$x(t)=C_1cos\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}t\right) + C_2sin\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}t\right)$

Prior to learning differential equations, when  I did physics I learned that the equation of motion of the spring was $x(t) = Acos\left(\omega t + \phi\right)$.

Both of these functions seem to be able to handle the same set of functions. The first equation seems to use the fact that it has an additional term to shift the function and avoid the need of $\phi$. Can it be shown that they are equivalent solutions or do they differ in some way?

Comment: Try expanding $\cos(\omega t+\phi)$ using the cosine addition formula.

Comment: Ah quite trivial indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s transform one into the other. Denote $\omega=\sqrt{k\over m}$ and start with

$$x(t)=A\cos(\omega t+\phi)=A\cos\phi\cos\omega t-A\sin\phi\sin\omega t$$

Which is in the first form with $C_1=A\cos\phi$ and $C_2=-A\sin\phi$